# Using PHP property overloading within class ($this)

Tags: php

I'm trying to trigger __get from within a class's method. See below. I thought that if I try to get the property by $this->user then __get will be triggered. But, it seems it isn't. Is this possible in PHP? Or does it only apply to external processes (e.g. $test->user which does trigger it)

```
<?php

class Test
{
    protected $user = 'Mario';

    public function __get($name)
    {
        echo "Getting '$name'\n";
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        $user = $this->user; // doesn't trigger __get
        //...
    }
}

$test = new Test;
$test->doSomething();
//echo $test->user; // this does trigger __get
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the class, `$user` is visible, so there's no need to call `__get`. `__get` is only called if the property cannot be resolved as is the case outside the class (if you changed it to be public instead of protected, `__get` wouldn't be called from outside of the class either).

If you want to force a call of `__get` in this situation, you will have to call it explicitly like `$this->__get('user')`.